# How to move an object depending on the camera in OpenGL.

Tags: opengl, graphics, camera, transformation

As shown in the image below. 
  [image: 3D Ball]

The user moves the ball by changing x,y,z coordinates which correspond to right,left, up, down, near, far movements respectively. But when we change the camera from position A to position B things look weird. Right doesn't look right any more, that because the ball still moves in previous coordinate frame shown by previous z in the image. How can I make the ball move in such a away that changing camera doesn't affect they way its displacement looks.

simple example: if we place the camera such that it looking from positive X axis, the change in the values of z coordinate now, will look like right and left movements. However in reality changing z should be near and far always.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. what you are saying. they look weird because of the camera position. I need to find a way to calculate the x,y,z according to the new camera position.

Answer (score 1):

Thought i will answer it here:

I solved it by simply multiplying the cam model view matrix to the balls coordinates.

Here is the code:

```
   glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, cam );
     matsumX=cam[0]*tx+cam[1]*ty+cam[2]*tz+cam[3];
     matsumY=cam[4]*tx+cam[5]*ty+cam[6]*tz+cam[7];
     matsumZ=cam[8]*tx+cam[9]*ty+cam[10]*tz+cam[11];
```

where tx,ty,tz are ball's original coordinates and matsumX, matsumY, matsumZ are the new coordinates which change according the camera.